# child views are overriding parent view's boundary. [react-native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to do as following in react-native. 
I am setting a borderRadius in the parent view. But the child is overriding that. So in the final view, the borderRadius is not visible

```html
export default class FlexDimensionsBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try removing the `flex: 1` on the parent View.
      // The parent will not have dimensions, so the children can't expand.
      // What if you add `height: 300` instead of `flex: 1`?
      <View style={{flex: 1, borderRadius:30, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
        <View style={{flexGrow: 10, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{flexGrow: 20, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{flexGrow: 30, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

is there anything which I am missing to add?

Comment: you need to set borderBottomRight, Left Radius on child view.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add `overflow: "hidden"` to your parent style